# Can you tell whats wrong with the SqlDataReader i returns "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@idorder"

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Hi since  I am using the using-statement, my disposable connections should be handled once it leaves the statement but my code is hard coupled in other methods in the program where I poll the db or get information. Therefore I have decided to add conn.Open() and conn.Close() to avoid timeout errors or to leave many Database connections open at the same time. I keep getting an error I am not familiar with and that is:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@idorder"

Is it relevant to my paramenter?
What am I doing wrong?

Hope this helps other devs out there starting out with ADO.NET

```
public List<LogModel> GetLatestLogsOnEachSystemId(
       {
            List<string> _systemIds = new List<string>();
            _systemIds.Add("MA");
            _systemIds.Add("MB");
            _systemIds.Add("DY");
            _systemIds.Add("FA");

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < _systemIds.Count; i++)
                {
                    string systemId = _systemIds[i];

                    var querystring = "select top 1 * " +
                                        "from dbo.RadarMF30_log " +
                                            "where SYSTEM_ID = @id" +
                                                "order by Log_writing_time desc";


                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querystring, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", systemId);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    conn.Close();

                    var model = new LogModel
                    {
                        errorCode = reader.GetString(0),
                        errorMsg = reader.GetString(1),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 "select top 1 * " +
    "from dbo.RadarMF30_log " +
    "where SYSTEM_ID = @id" +
    "order by Log_writing_time desc";
```

There is no space between `@id` and `order`.

That's why it thinks there is a variable called `@idorder`

Comment: That must be it. Meaning that: 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable ”@idorder" 

Should have been interpreted as something is wrong with the stringQuery or the cmd.CommandText.

Comment: @Ahuneajéoahe Exactly

Comment: Good catch, I suggest you to improve your answer suggesting to use the verbatim char to build this kind of string.

Comment: @Steve If it were me, I would prefer to use a stored procedure to access data via the database instead of creating a string in the c# code but you are right. If you were to create a string in this manner, I would suggest using a verbatim char

Comment: There are two religions here. One that I will call "extremists" and one that I will call "heretics". The first believes that everything must be written in a sp to get the best performance and a clear separation of tasks, the second believes that simple queries like this and without particular parameterizations can be left in the code to avoid excessive maintenance in case of changes

Comment: @Steve it amazes me that people still have hangups on the "best performance" part of that sentence; that was true once, and there *are* other reasons (separation of tasks, isolation, etc) - but the performance thing hasn't been true for quite some time, unless we're talking about commands that are large enough to take more than a packet to transmit, etc

Comment: I totally agree with you about performances. Nevertheless it is an argument that I hear very often. In these days I work as consultant and whenever I see a lot of SP containing just a _select something_ with simple parameters I start to point a finger...

Answer (score 1):

JamesS and Yaman have already covered the fundamental problem, but: as a general tip, if you're going to have SQL in C#, *verbatim string literals* (`@"..."`) avoid almost all white-space problems:

```cs
    const string query = @"
select top 1 *
from dbo.RadarMF30_log
where SYSTEM_ID = @id
order by Log_writing_time desc";
```

(note: it doesn't have to be a `const` - just... there's also no need for it to be a variable here)

As a side note: this is the kind of scenario that also works very well with tools like "Dapper" to avoid messing with ADO.NET at all:

```cs
    var model = conn.QuerySingle<LogModel>(@"
select top 1 *
from dbo.RadarMF30_log
where SYSTEM_ID = @id
order by Log_writing_time desc", new { id = systemId });
```

No more messing with the command and parameter nuances, or worrying about whether you've closed the connection too early (look closely: you've closed the connection too early).

---

As a side note: you might also want to avoid `select *` - it can cause two different kinds of problems:

- bringing back lots of large columns (CLOB/BLOB etc) that you don't need, impacting performance
- sometimes, just sometimes, the columns aren't in the order you expect; if you bind by *ordinal* (`GetString(0)` etc in your code), this can have huge impact; note that "Dapper" binds by *name*, so this isn't as much of a problem here (assuming the names match well enough for the library to figure out what you meant)

Answer (score -1):

because there is no space between @id and order, it thinks the parameter name is @idorder, which is not provided

```
var querystring = "select top 1 * " +
                                        "from dbo.RadarMF30_log " +
                                            "where SYSTEM_ID = @id " +
                                                "order by Log_writing_time desc";
```

or

```
var querystring = "select top 1 * " +
                                        "from dbo.RadarMF30_log " +
                                            "where SYSTEM_ID = @id" +
                                                " order by Log_writing_time desc";
```

Comment: I *think* this is being downvoted a little mostly because it doesn't really add anything compared to the answer that was there 10 minutes earlier; but: it is still right